# How to configure react-router to render proper layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to configure proper routing for react app to show layout of followed schema  https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=2352043018150167&set=pcb.2534370943249564&type=3&theater&ifg=1 
First level is the navbar (always visible) and the main window which should render sidebar and list of products. After click on a product the details of product should render (sidebar still visible). In the menu you can choose contact which causes to render contact details in main window (now sidebar is not visible). I cannot figure out how to properly construct routing to change main window. I've tried few things but there is always sth wrong. Please, could you give me a hand? See my code below.

```
<HashRouter>    
        <Navbar /> 
        <Switch>
            <Route > 
            <section className="main-container"> 
                <Sidebar />
                <div className="product-container">
                    <Route path="/" render={Main}/>
                    <Route path="product/:name" render={(products, addedProduct) => 
                    <ProductItem products={products} addedProduct={addedProduct}/>} /> 
                </div>
            </section>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/subpage/:name" component={Subpage} />                            
            <Route path="*" component={NotFound} /> 
        </Switch>       
 </HashRouter>
```

Comment: How are you rendering contact? I don't even see an URL end point for contact.

Comment: You are right, I just forgot to explain that it is rendered as the params in subpage component. Sorry for this misleading description.

Comment: I did some changes and tried this:
`<Route render={ (props) => 
   props.location === "/" ? (
   <MainLayout loading={loading} error={error} products={products} />
) : (
   <ProductItem products={products} addProduct={addProduct}/>
) 
}/>`
but it doesn't work. It renders first component and tries to render second one. Except that, I wanted to pass the param in the match, but I don't how? Could you please give me a clue?

Comment: I don't think it's recommended to conditionally render components like that. You should separate that route into multiple routes, one for MainLayout at '/' and another for ProductItem, maybe at something like 'product/:id'